# Is there any way to assign "Alt" property while using Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, accessibility

I have written code like this:

```
<rect x="40" y="40" width="40" height="40" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" role="img"></rect>
```

Here I have assigned role as Image so how can i assign "alt" property to it?

And not possible to have `alt`, then how will it describe the chart while narrator is used and focus will go there?

Comment: You can add `title` and `desc` tag to explain the chart.

Comment: Could you prepare a working example of what you already have?

Comment: @Raviteja titles aren't read to a screen reader. I would use the aria-label property.  Or even put some sr-only text inside the rect

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to put the entire graph in a container and have an `aria-label` on the container and `aria-hidden="true"` on the graph itself.  The `alt` attribute is only valid on the `<img>` tag and `<input type="image">`.

```html
<div role="img" aria-label="bar chart showing...">
  < <!-- whatever your highchart container tag is --> aria-hidden="true">
    <rect...>
  </whatever>
</div>
```

Comment: This would've been my solution aswell